# Why does my PowerShell Prompt Require the User to Answer Twice?

Tags: powershell, prompt

In a portion of a DOS batch file, I have a PowerShell command that prompts for a response and checks to ensure that the response contains 6-10 numbers. It works, except that the user has to enter the response twice. I have also noticed that when prompted the second time, there is a space immediately after the prompt. The space is not there the first time. here is the code:

```
:GET_SUFFIX

REM Prompt the user for the suffix using PowerShell

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& { $valid = $false; while (-not $valid) { $input = Read-Host 'Enter the Suffix (6 to 10 numbers)' ; if ($input -match '^\d{6,10}$' -and $input -notmatch '[^\d]') {$valid = $true; Write-Output $input } else { Write-Error 'Invalid input' } } }"') do set "var5=%%a"

REM code continues here if the suffix is valid

echo Suffix is valid: %var5%
```

And here is what it looks like when executed:

```
Enter the Suffix (6 to 10 numbers):123456

Enter the Suffix (6 to 10 numbers): 123456  <-- note the space after the colon

Suffix is valid: 123456
```

I tested the code with <6 numbers and >10 numbers and it validates properly, but the user always has to enter the response twice. My hunch is that it has something to do with the WHILE loop, but I am completely stumped.

Comment: As aside, `$input` is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell. Use a different variable name there

Comment: I changed $input to $sufin in all three places. Now it prompts only once, but it does not validate the entry and returns null.. I am new to PowerShell, so I may not know what I am doing.

Comment: There are *four* occurrences of `$input` in your script…

Comment: Thanks. I wound up converting the script to Python via ChatGPT and with some very minor tweaking, it works perfectly now in Python.

Comment: If that's the whole .bat file, it works for me.

Comment: Picky aside: No version of DOS can run PowerShell. The legacy `cmd.exe` shell is _not_ the same as DOS. You might have a batch file, but if it can run PowerShell it isn't a _DOS_ batch file.